# How to change primary group on Windows without ActiveDirectory?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, user-settings

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 using WorkGroup only (no Active Directory) with some local users and groups.
Is that possible to change the primary group of some local users?
I couldn't find a relevant button when setting local users and groups. Couldn't find on Google too.

It's necessary since I have to comply with the policy of one of the tools installed on this host.

If possible - how to do so?

Thanks

Comment: user properties - member of ?

Comment: The users are members of "None" and "Dev".
I'd like the primary group to be "Dev"

Answer (score 1):

You can't set that in a workgroup, as the group 'memberof' change from computer to computer. there is no weight on the group membership.

A workaroung is to make the group Dev 'memberof' the group None.